# Does this example of "reverse induction" work?

Tags: logic, graph-theory

Say we've shown that some statement $P(1)$ is true. Suppose that we can show $P(m) \iff P(m-1)$. Then, we will have shown $P(m) \iff P(1)$, so $P(m)$ is true. This makes sense, right?

So, with more context, let's say that we would like to show a graph that depends on $n$ with certain properties exists. Then, if we show that it exists for $n = 1$ and then we show that if a graph exists for arbitrary $n$ then we may get the $n-1$ case through edge/vertex deletions, can we say it holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$? To be more precise, is this general vertex/edge deletion a "reversible process"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**False theorem.** For all $n$, there is a simple graph with $n$ vertices and $n^2-1$ edges.

**Proof.** This exists for $n=1$: take the graph with $1$ vertex and no edges.

Suppose it exists for $n$ vertices. Then by deleting a vertex of some degree $k$, and then deleting $(2n-1)-k$ more edges arbitrarily, we get a simple graph with $n-1$ vertices and $(n-1)^2-1$ edges.

---

This is an instance of the problem. In general, deleting things is not reversible, since you may end up getting from an impossible graph to a possible graph by deleting the places where it's impossible. Even in cases where it *is* reversible, your proof would be cleaner if you constructed the graphs "forward" rather than "backward".

Comment: Awesome, thanks a bunch for a nice example. The notion of deleting impossible edges/vertices is what I was worried about.

Answer (score 1):

In your first paragraph, you stated showing implication in both directions and the statement makes sense. In fact, the forward implication is the standard case in normal induction

However, in your second paragraph, you showed only an implication for the reverse direction. You can only claim that if you proved the case for some fixed $k$, and then if $P(k)\implies P(k-1)$, the statement holds true for all $n\leq k$. This is known as backwards induction. You can't say anything about $n>k$.

(Correct me if my interpretation of what you meant is wrong. Because if what you want to show is the existence of a graph and you have shown a graph exist for some arbitrary $k$, you don't need induction?)

Another common induction technique in graphs is [Forward-Backward Induction](https://brilliant.org/wiki/forward-backwards-induction/).

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at is: let's say you want to show for every $n$ there exists a graph that satisfies some property. If you assume a graph $G_{m}$ satisfies the property and through edge/vertex deletion you obtain another graph $G_{m-1}$ that satisfies the property, then since edge/vertex deletion is reversible (by just unioning the deleted edges/vertices to their respective sets), you've shown "$P(m) \iff P(m-1)$." Now, what I'd like to say is that if I've shown the property holds for a base case $G_{1}$, then I've shown it for all $n$. I think I'm assuming the conclusion in some way.

Comment: I assume some choice of edge/vertex deletion is needed in your deletion? I don't think it's usually reversible as you claimed. Else, why can't you show it through the normal induction?

Comment: I could show it through regular induction, I agree, but I'm curious to know if this is equivalent. But yeah I think that your point about the choice of edge/vertex deletion is what kills this idea... I guess I am assuming that I may add edges/vertices that build up my base case to higher cases.

Comment: What you've said is actually stronger. Actually I suppose it can be stretched to say it's equivalent (well-ordering principle and stuff), but I will need to think about it.

If you've shown $P(k)\Leftrightarrow P(k-1)$, showing that $P(k)$ is true for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is sufficient to prove the whole thing yes.